# Opening Nautilus or RhythmBox from webpage

Tags: bash, debian, shell, php

I was wondering, is there any way to open either rhythm box or nautilus from a webpage html button using php. I have attempted exec, and shell_exec and neither worked. And to be clear the webpage is local and I want nautilus or rhythm box to open on the computer that is hosting the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an html file like this one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The html file</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/action.php">
            <button>
                Launch Nautilus
            </button>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

In action.php, you would call the required command:

```
<?php

// Launch your command
system("nautilus");

// Redirect to index.html
header('Location: /');   

?>
```

To test this, I used the builtin php server:

```
php5 -S 127.0.0.1:8000
```

And I went to http://127.0.0.1:8000 in my browser (firefox). It did start nautilus.